# xrandr can't find gamma on VirtualBox Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, xrandr

I have a fresh install of `Ubuntu 14 32-bit` guest on a `Windows` server host. As usual, the default resolution is so small that I'm not able to see any window in its entirety.

My usual procedure is:

1. Install `Guest Additions`
2. Install `DKMS`
3. Install the correct/up-to-date linux `headers`
4. Reboot, hope it's fixed, but if not
5. Use `gtf` to get a modeline
6. Use `xrandr --newmode` and `xrandr --addmode`

However, after going through this process several times including re-installing Guest Additions, there is still only the 1 prohibitively small resolution available and `Auto-scale` is still greyed out from the VirtualBox toolbar.

`xrandr` tells me that it `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`.

Do I need to edit some `X`-related configuration file or something? I saw an unconfirmed comment/solution on another forum to that effect, but I was not able to successfully follow that solution using the provided link (which was http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQVideoModes).

Comment: this is really a question for SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Well I can't move it or delete it so don't just downvote because you'd prefer it on SU

Comment: I can't move it because someone put a bounty on it.

Comment: Since this shows up as an early result on Google, you should answer it or link to the SuperUser question.